# Fastlane Gym change provisioning profile only for one target

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I am trying to setup `Jenkins` with `fastlane`. I got two targets in my project - main app and watch kit extension. When I try to change profile for Ad Hoc signing with `xcargs`, `gym` change profile for all targets and my builds fail.

This is my gym command.

```
gym(scheme: "MyApp", 
      workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace",
      xcargs: "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER='MyApp Ad Hoc'")
```

This is output.

```
Building MyApp/MyApp WatchKit App [Release]
[08:34:48]: ▸ Check Dependencies
[08:34:48]: ▸ ❌  Provisioning profile "MyApp Ad Hoc" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.
```

How to change profile only for a specific target?
Thank you.

Comment: Try changing the project signing settings to manual. Have a look at this - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/5608

Comment: Are you using 1 lane for both schema ?

Comment: @FaresBenHamouda Hm.. I just started to use fastlane. Not sure how to create two lanes for different schemas and then got one ipa file.

Comment: @EugeneTrapeznikov Have you solved your problem? I am facing the same issue now. I have seen your question on github, but there is no answer for this.

Comment: Same issue. Have you solved your problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the provisioningProfiles option as follows:

```
gym(
  ...
  export_options:{
    signingStyle: "manual",
    provisioningProfiles:{
        "com.myapp.iosapp": "match AdHoc com.myapp.iosapp"
    }
```

Comment: Is it really working?

Comment: I have not tested it in 4 years, and I no longer work there, but it did work back then.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `export_options` at all, if you correctly define `sigh` for every target.

```
cert()
sigh(
  adhoc: options[:adhoc],
  app_identifier: options[:bundle_id],
  provisioning_name: options[:provisioning],
  ignore_profiles_with_different_name: true,
)
sigh(
  adhoc: options[:adhoc],
  app_identifier: options[:share_bundle_id],
  provisioning_name: options[:share_provisioning],
  ignore_profiles_with_different_name: true,
)
build_ios_app(
  workspace: PLZ_WORKSPACE,
  scheme: options[:scheme],
  clean: true,
  export_method: options[:adhoc] ? "ad-hoc" : "app-store",
  export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
  output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH,
)
```

Remember that this way you need to manually install your provisioning profiles on CI machine or wherever you gonna run this out.